# free hotel wifi pushing an iframe at the top of each page

Tags: javascript, http, iframe, tcp

First, how is the stream edited on the fly? For every website I visit, there is a black bar telling me how much WiFi time I have left.

Second, how do I get rid of it?

Rather confused...

Comment: This is off topic; but out of sheer curiosity, What happens if you go to https://encrypted.google.com/?

Comment: It still appears; any and all SSL websites still have it.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to tag you, @vcsjones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The websites are being processed by a [transparent proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy).  As for how to get rid of it... pay for internet or write you own proxy that can remove the frame added by the provider.

Comment: I can tunnel through a SOCKS proxy, though as far as I can tell, that will be slower.

Comment: Also, what is a transparent proxy? And there is not a paid option; it's just complimentary.

Comment: tunneling would work and will be slow as you said.

Comment: Transparent proxy is a network redirect.  The router you are using is redirecting all of your web calls to a secondary webserver that reads the incomming request and then rewriting the request to add the banner.  It can also do things such as cache and filter sites.

Comment: Oh, that is irritating. Thank you though!